# Is it possible to update someone's Facebook News Feed or Wall when a site adds new content?

Tags: api, facebook

I am working on a site that uses "facebook connect". To use this option the user must still signup for an account the regular way through the site's internal registration system, i.e. they pick a username/password and 
enter their email, they then verify their address by clicking on the activation link sent to them. This information is stored in our database. Once they signin, they can "link" their facebook account with their new internal site account.

The benefit to this is, now whenever they click on the like button on one of our site pages, it will appear posted on their wall and news feed. Another benefit is they no longer has to signin with their internal site credentials. The still can if they want, 
but clicking on the "signin with facebook" option will also work. And of course if they are already logged into facebook then just clicking on that option would log one in, they don't even have to enter their credentials.

Anyway my question is if it's somehow possible to update a user's newsfeed and/or wall whenever our site adds new content? Does the facebook developer API allow any such option? Perhaps a rss feed we can provide that will be read by facebook and all users with their 
accounts linked to our site will receive these updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The user will need to accept that you are going to get access to post to their wall and such, the permission API key is `publish_stream`.

Read more about it under the following link:

- [Permissions - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

> ### publish_stream
>
> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. **With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access**. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.